# Find a surface or 3-manifold whose fundamental group is $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \rtimes (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

I know by [Van Kampen](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATchapters.html)'s Theorem that we can obtain $\pi_1(S_1 \vee S_1) = \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$, so I am wondering if we can construct a surface or 3-manifold whose fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}_n  * \mathbb{Z}_2$ or even $\mathbb{Z}_m  \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_n$.

This might be an interesting problem because I have written semidirect product $\rtimes$ rather than the free product $*$. A torus knot $K$ is defined in Hatcher as the image of an [embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding) of a map $f : S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^3 \subset S^3$ given by $z \mapsto (z^m, z^n)$ then the fundamental group $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3 - K)$ is $Z_m \ast Z_n$ possibly up to some number-theoretic conditions.  Hatcher doesn't quite give you the answer.

I think the [semidirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) product $\mathbb{Z}_m  \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_n$ is unique.  We have to specify $\mathbb{Z}_m \lhd G$ and then $G = \mathbb{Z}_m \ltimes \mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: This looks like a homework. Voted to close.

Comment: @MarkSapir I've been out of school 5 years.

Comment: Regarding uniqueness, there is always the direct product $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, and sometimes that's the only one (if $m$ does not divide $\varphi(n)$).  If we do have a non-Abelian semi-direct product, then it's unique for $n$ square-free at least, and I think in general.

Comment: Also, since the semi-direct product is a quotient of the amalgamated product, you should be able just to take a suitable cover of your $\mathbb R^3 \setminus K$, no?

Comment: In the reference you cite it is shown that $\pi_1({\mathbb R}^3-K)$ is the group generated by two elements $a$ and $b$ subject to the relation $a^m=b^n$. This group is torsionfree (as is true for all knots, not just torus knots) and it has ${\mathbb Z}_m*{\mathbb Z}_n$ as the quotient group when the center, which is the infinite cyclic group generated by the element $a^m=b^n$, is factored out.

Comment: @LSpice , regarding your second comment, I think you have the Galois correspondence the wrong way round: quotients are realised as deck groups, not as fundamental groups of covering spaces.

Comment: @HJRW, thanks; I thought something looked wrong there.

Comment: I am happy that this question survived. Even it is easy for specialists, it contains quite interesting details as you can see from the answers and comments:  1) is dihedral group subgroup of $S^3$; 2) what abelian groups can be fundamental groups of 3-manifolds. Such details are useful for persons like me who are learning 3-manifolds. This is good homework to do :)

Comment: Thurston's book "Three-dimensional Geometry and Topology" (not the notes) also has a fairly nice, self-contained discussion of 3-manifolds with finite fundamental group in the elliptic manifolds chapter. More generally, I have always found his flow charts at the end of the book to be really useful laying bare the relations between certain group properties and the geometric classification of 3-manifolds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See pp. 449--457 of Peter Scott's article *The geometries of 3-manifolds* for a complete description of all 3-manifolds with finite fundamental group. The article is available on his [website](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~pscott/).  There don't seem to be any with dihedral fundamental groups (see Allen Hatcher's comment below), but the fundamental groups of the *prism manifolds* are the *binary dihedral groups*, i.e. non-split central extensions of $D_{2n}\cong \mathbb{Z}/n\rtimes\mathbb{Z}/2$ by $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: The fundamental groups of prism manifolds are not the dihedral groups themselves but the {\it binary\/} dihedral groups $D^*_{2n}$ which are the preimages of the subgroups $D_{2n}\subset SO(3)$ under the projection $S^3\to SO(3)$. Thus $D^*_{2n}$ maps onto $D_{2n}$ with a ${\mathbb Z}/2$ kernel.

Comment: @AllenHatcher: Then I must have misunderstood the nomenclature. What should one call the quotients of the 3-sphere by the free dihedral actions that Scott describes on page 451 of his article?

Comment: This seems to be a mistake in Scott's paper.  He says that certain subgroups of the unit quaternion group $S^3$ are either cyclic, dihedral, or generalized quaternion (also known as binary dihedral). From this he deduces in particular that dihedral groups act freely on $S^3$.  However, $S^3$ has a unique element of order $2$, the quaternion $-1$, so $S^3$ cannot contain dihedral subgroups.  On Scott's webpage there is a list of errata for this paper but it does not include this one.

Comment: @AllenHatcher: thanks for the useful clarification. I’ll correct the answer shortly.

Answer (score 2):

A connected sum of the appropriate lens space and $\mathbb{R}P^3$ will have fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}_m \ast \mathbb{Z}_2.$ Otherwise, the only abelian fundamental groups of $3$-manifolds are $\mathbb{Z},$ $\mathbb{Z}^3$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ - see Stefan Friedl's notes (introduction to 3-manifolds and their fundamental group), so that rules out interesting direct products.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative to HJRW's answer, which also will rely on Perelman's affirmative resolution to the Poincare conjecture. In this case, we are using using it to say that 3-manifolds with finite fundamental group are covered by $S^3$. The problem can be reduced to this because a classification of 2-manifolds shows the only 2-manifold with finite order elements in $\pi_1$ is $RP^2$ and $\pi_1(RP^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Scott's paper tells us that any manifold with finite fundamental group admits a homomorphism with non-trivial kernel onto the orientation subgroup of a spherical triangle group.

However, Thurston's book (see below) has a classification of Elliptic 3-manifolds (those covered by $S^3$) and your problem can be solved using two statements which are rather self-contained.

Exercise 4.4.3 says that the only order 2 element of O(n+1) that acts freely on $S^n$ is the antipodal map. So for you, $n$ must be odd in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Then Proposition 4.4.4 shows that the only admissible semi-direct product in this case is in fact the direct product, since the antipodal map is just -Id in $O(4)$ which commutes with everything.

*Thurston, William P.*, Three-dimensional geometry and topology. Vol. 1. Ed. by Silvio Levy, Princeton Mathematical Series. 35. Princeton, NJ: Princeton University Press. x, 311 p. (1997). [ZBL0873.57001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0873.57001).